# Xcode link error: file too small for architecture armv7

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, linker-errors

I get this strange linker error:

> ld: in /Users/.../test project/iSMP.framework/iSMP, file too small for architecture armv7
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

Xcode vers: 4.0.2

If I compile for simulator, i get

> ... file too small for architecture i386

google doesn't help at all..

I already tried to:

- re-add the framework
- clear search path
- move framework to a different directory and re-add.

Update: output from lipo -info libiSMP-2.1.a

> Architectures in the fat file: libiSMP-2.1.a are: armv6 armv7 i386

so, it's not from architecture mismatch;

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Clean build solved this for me ...

Comment: These steps for me solved the problem: 1. Close Xcode 2. Clean DerivedData Folder 3. Rebuild

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've received the solution from the support team of this framework (thanks guys):

> Symbolic links are turned into flat files when they are moved from
>   OS/X to Windows. The iSMP framework has the following structure: 
>   iSMP.framework / iSMP (symbolic link pointing to libiSMP-2.1.a) /
>   Headers / libiSMP-2.1.a
>
> To fix the issue, you might open the terminal application on Mac and
>   move to the iSMP.framework directory. When you type 'ls -l iSMP'
>   command you will notice that the iSMP file has no longer the 'l'
>   attribute. You should then recreate the symbolic link by deleting the
>   iSMP file. type then 'ln -s libiSMP.2.1.a iSMP' .This will create the
>   link.
>
> You may now rebuild the project.
>
> Another solution to fix the problem is to delete the iSMP file and
>   rename libiSMP-xx.a to iSMP.

**TL/DR:  Symbolic links are turned into flat files when they are moved from OS/X to Windows. You need to renew them.**

Comment: This helped my issue.  I recreated the symlink and it worked.

Comment: I had similar issue with libjpeg.dylib, i replaced the whole dylib itself.